# C# Download price data csv file from https instead of http

Tags: c#, csv

I had a line of code which would open a csv file from Yahoo Finance website which was;

DataPath = "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csvs=AMZN&d=3&e=31&f=2006&g=d&a=4&b=30&c=1996&ignore=.csv";

Now the site has been changed so that to download the same csv file the code the web site uses is;

https://query1.finnace.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/AMZN?period1=1492582784&period2=149517474784&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=g4bOimZe.IF

When I use this in my code it does not download the file

I get that new code when I hover over the Download Data on the web page;
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN/history?p=AMZN

I wonder if I have to use code to log in to the secure website first even though there is no log in or password needed. Can anyone verify this or is it something else I am doing

Comment: By the looks of it you need to go to the short URL (your last one) to get the download link as it changes..

Comment: Can I add that the code I want to use is;